# Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined

Tags: protractor

my test were working fine, but after chrome update it stopped working and I get this error . :

`Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"`

I am using fowling versions :

`npm --version 6.9.0`

`node --version v10.15.3`

`protractor --version Version 5.4.2`

`Chrome Version : Version 74.0.3729.157 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

`Chrome Driver version : chromedriver_2.46`

Comment: Which chromedriver version are you using?